# What would qualify as a typo?

Tags: word-meaning

Consider these errors:

> Answer with yesor positive

1. The spacing error in "yesor" is it a typo or a formatting error or both?
2. If the writer meant "yes or no" but for some reason the word *positive* found its way in place of *no* would that be a typo, a formatting error, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Typography is the skill of presenting text in print, or by extension on a screen.

A typo (short for typographic error) is a minor error of the presentation of text on the page. Omitting a space is a typo, choosing the wrong word is not a typo.

However, telling someone that they have made a spelling mistake, grammar mistake, or have used the wrong word is critical of a person's skill at English, and by implication their intelligence. A person might feel insulted by being told that they have made this type of mistake. On the other hand, a typo is considered to be a minor error, and being told that you have made a typo isn't insulting. So you see people using "typo" to be polite.

The "yesor" is a typo. The mistake of replacing "no" with "positive" is not a typo, but it may be called one for politeness.

Properly, typos are formatting errors, but "formatting error" suggests a longer mistake, such as the incorrect use of different fonts.